Mesh turned Black in Sculpting Workspace
I'm currently working on sculpting a human head in Blender 3.6 LTS. Everything was going well until I accidentally pressed Shift+A while using the Mesh Filter brush. Suddenly, my entire mesh turned black. Notably, I'm not in Edit Mode. I've attached screenshots and brush properties. If anyone knows what's happening, please reach out.
Before pressing Shift+A:

After pressing Shift+A:

Mesh Filter Brush Properties:

If you need further details, feel free to ask, and I'll be happy to provide them along with any necessary screenshots.

I believe the change in color is to indicate that the mesh filter has been added to the entirety of your mesh, such as how Shift+A will select all the geometry in edit mode. IN order to reverse this, try setting the strength to 0 and pressing Shift+A again.

You have masked your object by accident, press AltM to unmask.

Thanks for the answer but I think, that this is a serious bug in blender. Why I am saying this? Well, opened that project today and when pressed Shift + A, Blender suddenly shut down.. I don't know why but whenevr I press Shift + A in that project, blender just dont like it. So I think maybe the black colour was also some bug.
